# Selenium Webdriver not execute javascript event in div element

Tags: javascript, selenium

**Environment description:**

1. Windows 7, 64 bit
2. IE 10, 64 bit
3. Selenium Webdriver 2.42.0

**Html snippet**

```html
<table cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=2 border=1>
      <tbody>
     <tr class=headerSA>
    <td>Info</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td  rowSpan=2><a onmouseup=WOP_showRightClickMenu(0) href="javascript:WOPAA_updateAccount(0)">Account Name </a></td>
     </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <div onmouseout="_JsMenu_onMenuItemOut();" id="_JsMenu_menuContainer"  _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">
      <div id="_JsMenu_menuLayer0">
        <div id="_JsMenu_menuLite0" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">
          <div id="_JsMenu_menuFg0" style=" HEIGHT: 72px; POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 1px; TOP: 1px; WIDTH: 141px; BACKGROUND-COLOR: #333333" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">
            <div onclick="_JsMenu_onMenuItemAction(this);" onmouseover="_JsMenu_onMenuItemOver(this);" id="_JsMenu_menuItem0">
              <div id="_JsMenu_menuItemText0" style=" POSITION: absolute; COLOR: #000000; LEFT: 14px; TOP: 3px" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">P-ADD</div>
              <div id="_JsMenu_menuItemHilite0">P-ADD</div>
            </div>
            <div onclick="_JsMenu_onMenuItemAction(this);" onmouseover="_JsMenu_onMenuItemOver(this);" id="_JsMenu_menuItem1">
              <div id="_JsMenu_menuItemText1" style=" POSITION: absolute; COLOR: #000000; LEFT: 14px; TOP: 3px" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">P-Delete</div>
              <div id="_JsMenu_menuItemHilite1" style=" POSITION: absolute; COLOR: #ffffff; LEFT: 14px; TOP: 3px; VISIBILITY: hidden" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">P-Delete</div>
            </div>
            <div onclick="_JsMenu_onMenuItemAction(this);" onmouseover="_JsMenu_onMenuItemOver(this);" id="_JsMenu_menuItem2">
              <div id="_JsMenu_menuItemText2" style=" POSITION: absolute; COLOR: #000000; LEFT: 14px; TOP: 3px" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">P-bl-delete</div>
              <div id="_JsMenu_menuItemHilite2" style=" POSITION: absolute; COLOR: #ffffff; LEFT: 14px; TOP: 3px; VISIBILITY: hidden" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">P-bl-delete</div>
            </div>
            <div id="_JsMenu_menuFocusItem0" style=" POSITION: absolute; LEFT: 0px; TOP: 0px" _layer="_JsMenu_menuLyr">&nbsp;</div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**Selenium code operation**

1. Right Click on anchor link "Account Name". It will basically make
   visible the div element
2. Then select any item from right context menu
3. It will open a modal dialog.
4. Switch to modal dialog

**Result**

1. Using Actions [new
   Actions(driver).contextClick(element).build().perform()] right click
   is OK. Then click operation in div is not opening the model dialog.
2. Using javascript executor
   [executor.executeScript("onClick(arguments[0]);", profileElement);]
   modal dialog is opened but control is not returning. Javascript
   executor make a blocking call until return form modal dialog.

**Question:: Please help me if anyone have the answer**

1. **If it is a blocking call then how automation can be possible ?**
2. **Why click on div element is not fireing/executing onClick event in case of either element.click() or using Actions?**

Comment: On right-clicking, when the option menu opens, is it in the same window or is it in a frame ? Also, in the modal dialog box are you entering and/or retrieving something?